# How to disable transparency when a window is highlighted?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, window, transparency

I'm using KDE 5.5.5 and have enabled highlighting windows in task manager settings. The problem is, I have a lot of windows open and when highlighting some windows they are barely readable under a stack of transparent windows. How can I turn off transparency when a window is highlighted (so that the highlighted window is simply shown on the top)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it helps (there are an huge number of options and it can be a bit overwhelming).

Go to Applications -> Settings -> System Settings

Under **Workspace** click the **Desktop Behaviour** icon now click the **Desktop Effects** icon

Scroll down to **Translucency** and click the square config icon for loads of options

Comment: Unfortunately no option in translucency changes the behaviour of task manager's highlight. Even disabling translucency doesn't help.